# System.InvalidCastException - SQL to C++ - safe_cast<float>

Tags: c++, sql

I need to give my variable a value from SQL, this part of the code it's where the compiler stops, aparently it's maybe a convertion problem. In my database that column is designed as float.

```
float presion = safe_cast<float>(data[4]);
```

[Here is the code, every value gets to his variable until it reaches the floats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN8e1.png)

[This is my database, the value of 1.5 should go to the variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T39o9.png)

Comment: Post the code as text instead of an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`safe_cast` is not a standard c++ type casting.
If you change your code to:

`float presion = dynamic_cast<double>(data[4])`;

it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, I'm gonna post it here anyway for other people with the same problem.

Just change, float for double:

```
float presion = safe_cast<float>(data[4]);
```

For :

```
float presion = safe_cast<double>(data[4]);
```